# Prometheus zookeeper monitoring

Tags: apache-zookeeper, prometheus

i want to move zookeeper to being monitored by prometheus . 
i deployed jmx-exporter (sscaling/jmx-prometheus-exporter:0.1.0)

and got most of the metrics but some are missing , for example zookeeper.approximate_data_size and parnew metrics of the GarbageCollector

for example:
i get this par new metrics from the logstash with the same jmx exporter:
java_lang_GarbageCollector_LastGcInfo_memoryUsageAfterGc_used{name="ParNew",key="Par Survivor Space",}

but in the zookeeper i get only copy metrics:
java_lang_GarbageCollector_LastGcInfo_memoryUsageAfterGc_used{name="Copy",key="Metaspace",} 1.4809288E7

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason you are getting different GC metrics is that you are running the different JVMs with different memory settings/garbage collectors, and thus the metrics are different.

If Zookeeper is exposing a number via JMX, the JMX exporter should be returning it.

Comment: but when i monitor the same server wit datadog i do get this metric

Comment: That doesn't mean that datadog is retrieving that data via JMX. Zookeeper's JMX metrics are quite limited.

Comment: so i want to understand what retrieves this metric in datadog, the command: /etc/init.d/datadog-agent jmx list_everything | grep -i parnew on feeder returns the par new metric and on zookeeper nothing but both have this metric graph

Answer (score 0):

**To collect zookeeper metrics from Prometheus**

- Create **conf/java.env** file (my zookeeper configuration directory: /etc/zookeeper/conf/java.env) and below mentioned contents

  export SERVER_JVMFLAGS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10701 -javaagent:/opt/jmx_prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=10801:/opt/jmx_prometheus/config.yml $SERVER_JVMFLAGS"
- Restart zookeeper service, zookeeper JMX metrics can be collected from port 10801(as I configured this port above to get metrics)